# how to make different loop place in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display data so that when the value is an even number it goes in the left column, and when the value is an odd number it goes in the right column.
like this:

[image]

This is my code

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      dataSource: [
        {id = 0}
        {id = 1},
        {id = 2},
        {id = 3},
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <Content>
            <List
                refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                    onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh()}
                />
                }
                enableEmptySections={true}
                dataArray={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => this._renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID)}
                >
            </List>
          </Content>
    );
  }

  _renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID){
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <View>
                <Text>{id % 2 == 0}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
                <Text>{id % 2 != 0}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this will just show `true and false` or `false and true` as you don't make a if so each row will have both value in a row direction. The problem of this is that even with the condition you will have 4 row and not 2 row as in your example

Comment: can you give example with my code? @Clad Clad. thanks

Comment: are your sure your input is always number following each others ? or is it random  ?

Comment: random, but that loop can show in 2 row

Answer (score 0):

As a work around You can have a look at this jsfiddle

```
renderList() {
    const {ids} = this.state;
    return ids.map((id) => (<div style={{width: '40%', border: '1px solid grey', padding: 10}}>{id}</div>));
  }
```

in your render method you can do some styling to the parent div.

```
<div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', width: '100%'}}>
    {this.renderList()}
</div>
```

I know this is ReactJS specific code. but the same approach can be used in React-Native